# Programmatically switch parent tabs from modal view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

In my app, you can add a photo using a modal view. When the modal view gets dismissed, I want to automatically switch the tab bar controller to the second tab (the photo viewer screen).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795407/programmatically-pressing-a-uitabbar-button-in-xcode) about how to programmatically switch tabs, but I'm not sure where to put this code in the modal view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a delegate protocol and assign a delegate property to the viewController being presented modally, and make it inform its delegate when it's about to call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated after taking a picture.

edit: added some more information about implementation

On the view controller class you are presenting modally, you would declare a protocol:

```
@protocol YourUIViewControllerSubclassDelegate;
```

Then, you would add a property to your class:

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained)id <YourUIViewControllerSubclassDelegate>delegate;
```

finally, after your call the @end on your class interface declaration, you would complete the protocol:

```
@protocol YourUIViewControllerSubclassDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)viewController:(YourViewControllerSubclass *)viewController isBeingDismissedWithImage:(BOOL)imageTaken;
@end
```

So, inside your YourUIViewControllerSubclass, before calling dismissModalViewControllerAnimated, you would do:

```
[self.delegate viewController:self isBeingDismissedWithImage:YES or NO];
```

So, when you create YourUIViewControllerSubclass, you need to assign the delegate property. Whoever is the delegate of YourUIViewControllerSubclass needs to conform to the YourUIViewControllerSubclassDelegate protocol, and implement the protocol method. Inside this implementation of the protocol method, you would switch to whatever tab you would like to switch to.

Comment: Could you please provide a quick code example? I'm not sure where each of those pieces would go.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked, but now `viewDidLoad` isn't getting called on the tab I'm switching to. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: check if viewDidLoad has been called before. viewDidLoad will only be called when the view is loaded, and wont be called unless viewDidUnload has been called, or a new view controller instance has been created.

Comment: Actually, I meant to say `viewDidAppear` isn't getting called. `viewDidLoad` DOES get called. Is there any way to force `viewDidAppear` to get called?

Comment: Finally got this figured out - it was because I was calling the tab switch before dismissing the modal view. Once I switched the order, it worked fine.