# ViewDidAppear not getting called when programmatically switching TabBarController views

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'm programmatically switching TabBarController views from a modal view controller (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181677/programmatically-switch-parent-tabs-from-modal-view-controller)). The delegate correctly switches the tabs, but `viewDidAppear` isn't getting called in the newly presented tab. Is there any way to force viewDidAppear to get called? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this figured out - it was because I was calling the tab switch before dismissing the modal view. Once I switched the order, it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Force to call the viewDidAppear;

```
- (void)viewController:(YourViewControllerSubclass *)viewController isBeingDismissedWithImage:(BOOL)imageTaken {
  // Select the tabbar index (which is the second controller)
  [secondController viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem but rather goes around it, which could cause confusion down the road

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue before. 
In my TabBarViewController's `viewDidLoad()`, I selected other tab programatically as `selectedIndex = 3`. The target viewController's `viewDidAppear()` isn't called. But if I move `selectedIndex = 3` from `viewDidLoad()` to `viewDidAppear()`, the problem is solved.