# Change Tab Dynamically in iPhone using Storyboard Tabbar Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, tabbarcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically pressing a UITabBar button in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795407/programmatically-pressing-a-uitabbar-button-in-xcode)

I've four tabs in Main tabbar controller. On 1st Tab, there is "Dashboard" Page which is displayed when User registered with Device-ID.

For non-existing Users, It'll prompt a message for Registration. And By clicking on "OK" button, I want to jump on 4th Tab which is used for Set-Up module.

So, how can I set Tabbar index as done with older earlier versions and navigation in Tabbar ?

Please tell me any Solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the following line of code to get the tabBar begin with the 4 th tab selected when it will be presented

```
 [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement this code first If you are using Tabbar based Application in Storyboard.

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

Then,

```
[tabBar setSelectedIndex:3];
```

As you said : AppleDelegate